# StackOverflowException when using multiple classes and defining interface in opposite classes

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

I have the following example using [Unity dependency injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) installed using [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/3.5.1404/) and I have the following type of setup in my project. But when using two interfaces in constructors in the other class (see below code) throws an unhandled exception of type `'System.StackOverflowException'` in `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll`

Classes and interfaces setup:

```
public interface ITest1
{

}

public interface ITest2
{

}

public class Test1 : ITest1
{
    private readonly ITest2 _test2;

    public Test1(ITest2 test2)
    {
        _test2 = test2;
    }
}

public class Test2 : ITest2
{
    private readonly ITest1 _test1;

    public Test2(ITest1 test1)
    {
        _test1 = test1;
    }
}
```

Console application:

```
static IUnityContainer _container;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    LoadContainer();

    var two = _container.Resolve<Test1>();
}

private static void LoadContainer()
{
    _container = new UnityContainer();

    _container.RegisterTypes(
        AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
        WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
        WithName.Default);
}
```

So basically when resolving the Test1 class, it throws an exception as you can see below:

[image]

Comment: The exception is telling you ***EXACTLY*** what the problem is.  You have an infinite loop due to a dependency requiring a dependency requiring the original dependency.

Comment: Ah got it, so how would I resolve this, as I need Test2 in Test1 and viceverse.

Comment: You need to abstract the commonality into a third dependency that can be injected into both.  I can't give you a definitive answer because your sample is too abstract.

Comment: StackOverflowException on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

This exception is caused by Circular Dependencies.

The class `Test1` has a dependency on `ITest2` and the implementation has a dependency on `ITest1`. So when you resolve `ITest` it needs to satisfy the `ITest2` dependency. When the `Test2` dependecy is resolved it has a dependency on `ITest` which is where your `StackOverflowException` is coming from.

Comment: Thanks, so can you suggest a solution or a work around?

Comment: @Umair without knowing more about the classes there isnt much i can suggest other than removing one of the dependencies or finding some sort of middle ware class that uses `ITest1` and `ITest2` as depencies and manually build the classes.